# OpenCV Python with Cuda low FPS on GPU

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, nvidia

I have built OpenCV with Cuda for Python and am using the following lines to use GPU.

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(proto_file, weights_file)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
```

However, my FPS with GPU is about 1.8 while it is about 0.8 with CPU. In the task manager, my GPU utilization is displayed as about 5%.
My GPU is Nvidia GeForce MX130. How can I increase my GPU utilization and hence, my FPS?
To verify that my OpenCV installation allows GPU processing, I have used the following statements with the respective outputs.

```
cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
```

Output 1.

```
cv2.getBuildInformation()
```

Output:
'\nGeneral configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================\n  Version control:               unknown\n\n  Extra modules:\n    Location (extra):            G:/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules\n    Version control (extra):     unknown\n\n  Platform:\n    Timestamp:                   2021-09-24T15:28:43Z\n    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19043 AMD64\n    CMake:                       3.21.1\n    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019\n    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe\n    MSVC:                        1929\n\n  CPU/HW features:\n    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3\n      requested:                 SSE3\n    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX\n      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX\n      SSE4_1 (17 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1\n      SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2\n      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX\n      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX\n      AVX2 (31 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2\n      AVX512_SKX (7 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX\n\n  C/C++:\n    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES\n    C++ standard:                11\n    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.29.30133.0)\n    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG \n    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 \n    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe\n    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /MP   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG \n    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:fast     /MP /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 \n    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO \n    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL \n    ccache:                      NO\n    Precompiled headers:         NO\n    Extra dependencies:          cudart_static.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cudnn.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/lib/x64\n    3rdparty dependencies:\n\n  OpenCV modules:\n    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab world xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto\n    Disabled:                    -\n    Disabled by dependency:      -\n    Unavailable:                 alphamat cnn_3dobj cvv freetype hdf java js julia matlab ovis python2 python2 sfm viz\n    Applications:                tests perf_tests apps\n    Documentation:               NO\n    Non-free algorithms:         NO\n\n  Windows RT support:            NO\n\n  GUI: \n    Win32 UI:                    YES\n    VTK support:                 NO\n\n  Media I/O: \n    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)\n    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)\n    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)\n    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)\n    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)\n    JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)\n    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)\n    HDR:                         YES\n    SUNRASTER:                   YES\n    PXM:                         YES\n    PFM:                         YES\n\n  Video I/O:\n    DC1394:                      NO\n    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)\n      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)\n      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)\n      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)\n      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)\n      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)\n    GStreamer:                   NO\n    DirectShow:                  YES\n    Media Foundation:            YES\n      DXVA:                      YES\n\n  Parallel framework:            Concurrency\n\n  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)\n\n  Other third-party libraries:\n    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]\n           at:                   G:/opencv-gpu-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv\n    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)\n              at:                G:/opencv-gpu-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw\n    Lapack:                      NO\n    Eigen:                       NO\n    Custom HAL:                  NO\n    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)\n\n  NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.1, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)\n    NVIDIA GPU arch:             50\n    NVIDIA PTX archs:\n\n  cuDNN:                         YES (ver 7.6.5)\n\n  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)\n    Include path:                G:/opencv-4.4.0/opencv-4.4.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2\n    Link libraries:              Dynamic load\n\n  Python 3:\n    Interpreter:                 G:/python-projects/human-pose-estimation/venv/Scripts/python.exe (ver 3.9.6)\n    Libraries:                   C:/Users/tmakp/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/libs/python39.lib (ver 3.9.6)\n    numpy:                       G:/python-projects/human-pose-estimation/venv/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.21.2)\n    install path:                G:/python-projects/human-pose-estimation/venv/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-3.9\n\n  Python (for build):            G:/python-projects/human-pose-estimation/venv/Scripts/python.exe\n\n  Java:                          \n    ant:                         NO\n    JNI:                         NO\n    Java wrappers:               NO\n    Java tests:                  NO\n\n  Install to:                    G:/opencv-gpu-build/install\n-----------------------------------------------------------------\n\n'